Why do I get a 403 instead of being logged in?
I am building a project with some simple google oauth options, I had been testing and it had worked for more then a month now, I changed some code that accidentally booted me out of all accounts on my project, when trying to log back in to my google account in my app, I was met with a 403 (Access to localhost was denied. You don't have authorization to view this page.)
I obviously reverted the code and still the same issue...
Things I find weird are that if I try on other google accounts that I havent registered as test users in the google console, I get the usual "Access blocked: (MyApp) has not completed the Google verification process", and if I register that email as a test user in the console, then it lets me through, until I log back out of that account and now that one is blacklisted like the first one, I only have so many google accounts to conduct tests on haha
Is there some sort of blacklist somewhere I have missed, why are my accounts getting blocked?
Also, I have these errors in the console, can't remember if I had them before though...
Thanks

It is possible that you are missing permission when making the request.
Can you share the codebase?

Can you tell us what you changed?

I am not sure what to share haha, the codebase is starting to get pretty large but I changed some code in a vue component that was going to render what came back from a call to my backend which retrieved data on the youtube playlists of the user, I also made changes to a typescript file to add a retreivePlaylists function that clearly didn't work because I couldn't even print out the Authorizationheader

Also, the code is back to how it was before this error started happening, that's what I don't understand really (plus the fact that if google is blocking the request with a 403, I think this is more on the backend side and not my client code...)
